# Run a command each within a separate cmd window and with a different working directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want run a `npm start` command in each of four folders with a single batch file.

It should open a cmd.exe window for each of the four commands.

Comment: You want to run `npm start` _3 times_ in each folder? So you want to open cmd.exe in 12 separate windows simultaneously?

Comment: Sorry, edited. 4 times. 1 time for each folder. there will be 4 cmd.exe windows running npm start simultaneously @Mathias R. Jessen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `start` command in a script (batch file), perhaps? Example file `mynpm.cmd`:

```
@echo off
start "process 1" /d "path 1" npm start arg1 arg2 arg3
start "process 2" /d "path 2" npm start arg3 arg4 arg5
start "process 3" /d "path 3" npm start arg6 arg7 arg8
start "process 4" /d "path 4" npm start arg9 argA argB
```

...or something similar. (Run `start /?` at the cmd.exe command prompt for more information about how to use the `start` command.)